# Joining in MongoDB MapReduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have 2 collections.

**A:**
cid: is a mongo object id, like: ObjectId("xxxxxx")
sid: could be NULL, or a mongo object id as well, like: ObjectId("xxxxxxx")

**B:**
sid: is a mongo object id, like : ObjectId("xxxxxxxx")
name: is a string, like: "hello"

I want to get all documents in A (no matter sid is null, or not). If sid is null, then name is empty string: "". If NOT, then name is form B basing on sid.

When I looking for the answer, I know the map function should emit the same key on both collections.  BUT, in my case, I CANNOT use sid as key.  If I use sid as key, then I will miss the documents with sid id null (no name).  I think I must use cid as key.

If someone know how to solve it, please let me know. 
Thanks.

Update:

```
    A: 
    [
     {cid: ObjectId("59f7634b6260c927c0a144b0"), sid: ObjectId("59f7634b6260c927c0a144b1")},
     {cid: ObjectId("59f7634b6260c927c0a144b2"), sid: null}
    ]
    B: [{sid: ObjectId("59f7634b6260c927c0a144b1"), name: "hello"}]
```

I want to get

```
    [
     {cid: ObjectId("59f7634b6260c927c0a144b0"), sid: ObjectId("59f7634b6260c927c0a144b1"), name: "hello"},
     {cid: ObjectId("59f7634b6260c927c0a144b2"), sid: null, name: ""}
    ]
```

Comment: Far to abstract. Be more specific with sample documents and expected result as well as what has been done so far to solve it. You really should not be using mapReduce in any case where `.aggregate()` can be applied, and in modern releases there are not many places where it cannot be. So you really should be showing any attempt using that as well and explaining why. If you asked the question based on "old posts" about mapReduce performing "joins", then *"these are not the droids you are looking for..."*. The modern world uses aggregate instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Then how to use aggregate to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

```
db.getCollection('A').aggregate([{
    $lookup:
    { // lookup data from B using the "sid" fields as the join key
        'from': 'B',
        'localField': 'sid',
        'foreignField': 'sid',
        'as': 'b'
    }
}, {
    $unwind: { // flatten the "b" array
        path: "$b",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true // make sure we do not drop the non-matched documents from A
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "_id": 1,
        "cid": 1,
        "sid": 1,
        "hello": { $ifNull: [ "$b.name", "" ] },
    }
}])
```

Comment: Error: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$addFields'",
 "code" : 16436
} : aggregate failed :

Comment: Oh, so you're using a slightly older MongoDB version. Hold on, I'll update my code.

Comment: I am using mongodb 3.2

Comment: Yes, I've updated my code so it should work with MongoDB 3.2.